# regular expression to match Indian mobile phone numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression that should accept Indian mobile numbers. for example...

- 9788812345
- 9876512345
- 7891234567
- 8122212345

Comment: What are the possible patterns?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> ^(+91|0091)?[7-9][0-9]{9}$
> ```

this will work for you try it.

Answer (score 2):

[789][0-9]{9}, looking at the sample numbers given.  Prefixing an optional (+91|0)? could make it more usable.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
^[7-9][0-9]{9}$
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is

for mobile(without +91)

```
^[1-9][0-9]{9}$
```

for land line(std code 3 to 4 digits, and rest number of 6 to 8 digits)

```
^[0-9]\d{2,4}-\d{6,8}$
```